# Chrome becomes Unresponsive after opening pinned website

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome is being very annoying, and I need some help fixing the issue.

My company is using Chrome in a Windows Terminal Services environment. In Chrome, opening a **pinned website** (on any of our terminal servers) often (though not always -- it's intermittent) results in the browser locking up and Chrome throwing a "The pages have become unresponsive. Wait or Kill" message.

Here is a video of the issue occurring: http://screencast.com/t/4q1ZmWyz

We can reproduce the issue on many different websites, so I don't think that the website itself is the issue.

This issue *only* occurs when opening **pinned websites**. (To open a pinned website, you right-click on the Chrome icon and choose the website that you want to open). If you manually type in a URL, Chrome works fine. (It's somewhat of a long story, but our users rely heavily on pinned websites to do their work.)

We're using Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit). We've tried uninstalling/re-installing Chrome, and also tried deleting a user's `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome` folder. The issue still remains.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we found the culprit: [IBM's Trusteer Rapport](https://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/trusteer-rapport).

Apparently Rapport and Chrome don't get along, and Rapport can cause Chrome to behave strangely: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_f-kfcUQgkk

(Search the thread above for the word "Rapport").

After completely uninstalling Rapport, we can no longer reproduce the issue.